# Application fail over and blue / green deployment with WAS8.5

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, ibmhttpserver, blue-green-deployment

I am running WebSphere 8.5 with the following architecture: 1 IHS server load balancing on 2 application servers.

I have of course several applications deployed on the 2 AS and I have the impression that the IHS cannot detect that 1 application is not any more available on 1 AS.

I have stopped an application on only one of the AS with a script and the IHS keeps dispatching the requests to the one that is running the application and to the other one, resulting with this disgusting message: `SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /xxxxxxxx has not been defined.`

Is the finest granularity of the failover plugin the application server ?

I need to reduce downtime risk and to achieve blue / green deployment. I need somehow to update the route of the IHS server to ask it to load balance only on the one that is running the application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The plugin checks only the availability of the server. So it is not able to detect single application outages.

It is rather rare that only one application will fail on the particular server. Usually the whole server is unavailable, if there is a major problem with the application.

To enhance availability during updates, you can check out [Deploying and managing application editions with Intelligent Management](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twve_appedtop.html?lang=en) , which allows you to rollout new application version in less intrusive way.